# How many cards need to be picked at least?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> You have $50$ cards and you have the numbers from $1$ to $50$ written on them, and you randomly pick cards. How many cards do you need to pick out so you can ensure that at least $3$ cards with primes were picked?

**A** 38 **B** 39 **C** 40 **D** 50

I am going to say $50$, so we can ensure that every card is picked.

Comment: The worst case scenario is that you pick every number that is not prime before you select the third prime.

Comment: Picking out $50$ cards indeed ensures that at least $3$ cards with primes are picked, but you do not **need** to pick out $50$ to get that assurance.

Answer (score 3):

There are $15$ primes from $1$ to $50$, so $35$ numbers are NOT prime. If you take $38$ cards, at least $3$ of them must contain a prime number.

The correct answer is therefore $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Count how many nonprimes there are between $1$ and $50,$ then the *minimum* number of cards to pick is 3 more.